# What is the correct way to set args in rosparam?

Tags: roslaunch, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to launch the [Multimaster](http://ros.org/wiki/multimaster) node requiring parameter lists. Inside the list, I need to use an arg that would be used in other nodes in the same launch file. This is what I'd like in effect (it does not work):

```
  <arg name="robotname" default="robot1" />

  <node pkg="multimaster" type="master_sync.py" name="master_sync" output="screen" respawn="true"> 
    <param name="foreign_master" value="http://localhost:11311" />      
    <rosparam>
      local_pubs: [$(arg robotname)/status, /some_other_topics]
    </rosparam>
  </node>
```

What should be the correct way to get $(arg robotname) into the parameter list?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39085/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-args-in-rosparam?/) by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2268 on 2012-07-17

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-03-28**:
Pull request with a preliminary implementation of this feature here: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/203

**Comment by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on 2013-11-07**:
Have you found a workaround for this issue?

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-11-07**:
Nope, I've been busy with other things. My original implementation was pushed back to me by the ros-core team, but the followup ticket is still open: ( https://www.bountysource.com/issues/742041-add-substitution-args-parsing-to-roslaunch-yaml )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has since been implemented, set `subst_value="true"`:

```
<rosparam param="whitelist" subst_value="true">$(arg whitelist)</rosparam>
```

http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2015-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, you cannot use substitution args inside `<rosparam>` because roslaunch just parses the complete text using a yaml parser, i.e. no substitutions are done. On the other hand, you cannot create lists using `<param .../>` so I assume what you are trying is not possible at the moment. I think that this would be a nice feature to have. Maybe you should open a feature request at https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3